# Comparator does not sort if it encounters a null

Tags: java, eclipse, calendar, comparator, jcr

I am trying to do a custom sort of calendar objects (extracted from a Node class) with any nulls encountered pushed to the end when sorted.

This is my code:

```
public class CustomComparatorPubDate implements Comparator<Node> {

@Override
public int compare(Node o1, Node o2) {
    try {
        Calendar d1 = o1.getProperty("jcr:content/metadata/jcr:pubdate").getDate();
        Calendar d2 = o2.getProperty("jcr:content/metadata/jcr:pubdate").getDate();
        LOGGER.debug("d1: " + d1);
        LOGGER.debug("d2: " + d2);
        if (d2 == null && d1 == null) return 0;
        if (d1 == null) return 1;
        if (d2 == null) return -1;

        int compar = d1.compareTo(d2);
        LOGGER.debug("compar: " + compar);
        return compar;

    } catch (RepositoryException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

My call to the above class:

```
Collections.sort(listofnodes, new CustomComparatorPubDate());
```

I have a test array where one of the object property is deliberately left null for testing, where this fails. If I populate that property it seems to work fine.

Any idea what is wrong and how to tackle this?

P.S: Eclipse would not allow me to write this without the try/catch block.

Edit: In logs I see that it throws a `javax.jcr.PathNotFoundException`

Comment: What does _where this fails_ entail?

Comment: It does not sort. The list-array of interest is unchanged before and after the sort operation.

Comment: Please post the stacktrace.

Comment: I see your checking the calendar objects for null, but not the node objects. If your node obj is null, calling getProperty method could be a npe

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a little bug where if d1 is null you are sorting it before d2 even if d2 isn't null.

`if (d1 == null) return 1;`

So if you change this to return -1 it should sort the way you are looking for.

Comment: Nope. I tried and it still is the same. Thanks for trying.